How to manually add bias to model parameters and make this bias trainable for gradient backpropagation and updates
I have some tasks from different domains, and there's a base model called MetaModel that can perform regression. I want to add a task-specific bias to the parameters of the base model MetaModel when training different tasks. Currently, I'm using the method shown in the code below, but during gradient backpropagation, the gradients of MetaModelWithBias.biases are always None. I'd like to know how to update the parameters of MetaModelWithBias.biases to make them learnable.
The key codes for the task-specific bias are below:
for param in self.meta_model.parameters():
     param.data += self.biases[task_id]

The complete codes:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

class MetaModelWithBias(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, meta_model, num_tasks):
        super(MetaModelWithBias, self).__init__()
        self.meta_model = meta_model
        self.biases = nn.ParameterList([nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1)) for _ in range(num_tasks)])

    def forward(self, x, task_id):
        with torch.no_grad():
            for param in self.meta_model.parameters():
                param.data += self.biases[task_id]
        output = self.meta_model(x)
        return output

class MetaModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MetaModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)



# random some data
num_tasks = 5
input_size = 10
num_samples = 100
num_tasks = 5
X = torch.randn(num_samples, input_size)
task_ids = torch.randint(0, num_tasks, (num_samples,))

# create model
meta_model = MetaModel()
meta_model_with_bias = MetaModelWithBias(meta_model, num_tasks)

# training
num_epochs=10
optimizer = optim.SGD([
    {'params': meta_model_with_bias.meta_model.parameters()},
    {'params': meta_model_with_bias.biases.parameters() }
], lr=0.01)
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    outputs =0
    for i in range(num_samples):
        task_id = task_ids[i]
        output = meta_model_with_bias(X[i].unsqueeze(0), task_id)
        outputs+=output

    criterion = nn.MSELoss()
    targets = torch.randn(1, 1)
    loss = criterion(outputs, targets)

    print('\tMetaModelWithBias biases before backward',[parms for parms in meta_model_with_bias.biases],[parms.grad for parms in meta_model_with_bias.biases])
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    print('\tMetaModelWithBias biases after backward',[parms for parms in meta_model_with_bias.biases],[parms.grad for parms in meta_model_with_bias.biases])

    print('meta_model_with_bias params')
    for name, parms in meta_model_with_bias.named_parameters():
        print('-->name:', name, '-->grad_requirs:', parms.requires_grad,
              ' -->parameter:', parms,
              ' -->grad_value:', parms.grad)


Then I get:
    MetaModelWithBias biases before backward [Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.2255], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([-2.2697], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.7426], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([0.0925], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0564], requires_grad=True)] [None, None, None, None, None]
    MetaModelWithBias biases after backward [Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.2255], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([-2.2697], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.7426], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([0.0925], requires_grad=True), Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.0564], requires_grad=True)] [None, None, None, None, None]

thanks for your time!

Is there a reason you want to add the bias to the parameters themselves? Typically bias is added to activations

Actually, I'm studying the code for meta-learning model MAML. I aim to add task-specific parameters to the meta-parameter θ at the beginning of the local update for the i-th task. This would make the initial task specific parameter for this task θ’=θ+b[i].
For the MetaModel mentioned above, I'm using a linear layer as an example.

In your proposed version, two problems would indicate your biases aren't getting any gradient. First, you are using torch.no_grad which means no gradient computation is permitted, so in this scope, all requires_grad flags are set to False by design. Even removing that, you are deliberately bypassing gradient computation because the parameters are overwritten through their data attribute which means the gradients are not tracked!
Let alone the fact you are accumulating the biases, ie. after 10 iterations, you would have params += 10*biases which seems incorrect. In other words, in your implementation, there is no "resetting" of the parameters...
Now, of course, you probably did that to overcome the scary "Leaf variable was used in an in-place operation" error. This happens when you try to operate on a parameter in place, so this would fail:
param += self.biases[task_id]

Having it out of place makes no sense since param is just a scope variable, the underlying parameter remains unchanged.
After thinking about it, it seems the only way to make the gradient track back to the added bias, is to apply that layer manually via the functional approach. Instead of modifying the parameters on every iteration, you do it just before applying it (which fixes the issue highlighted above in bold).
Here is a possible implementation which ensures gradient computation on the biases:
class MetaModelWithBias(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, meta_model, num_tasks):
        super(MetaModelWithBias, self).__init__()
        self.meta_model = meta_model
        self.biases = nn.ParameterList([
              nn.Parameter(torch.randn(1)) for _ in range(num_tasks)])

    def forward(self, x, task_id):
        output = self.meta_model(x, self.biases[task_id])
        return output

class MetaModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MetaModel, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(10, 1)

    def forward(self, x, bias):
        return F.linear(x, self.fc.weight+bias, self.fc.bias+bias)


Thank you for providing possible implementations and raising insightful questions that helped me learn a lot. In fact, I'm currently developing meta-learning code based on MAML, with a spatio-temporal graph neural network as the base model. Following your suggestions, I might need to use torch.nn.functional.conv2d to set the task-specific weight. I'll give this approach a try. Thanks!
